# How to theme forum posts? (Custom author_pane template won´t work)

Tags: theming, nodes

I´m trying to get my author_pane template from the profiles to be different than my author_pane template in my forums.
I´m using Silver Bells forum theme.

After reading [the instructions](http://drupal.org/node/435866), I´ve managed to understand that the template that´s being called at the forum is "advanced-forum.naked.author-pane.tpl"

So, I´ve tried customizing that template (copying into my theme folder), with no success (Drupal don´t "take it", as if it´s not there).
Then I´ve tried changing the name to my forum theme: advanced-forum.silver_bells.author-pane.tpl
Nothing.
I´ve tried a few variants:
advanced-forum.silver_bells.author-pane.tpl
advanced-forum.silverbells.author-pane.tpl
advanced_forum.silver_bells.author-pane.tpl
advanced_forum.silverbells.author-pane.tpl
advanced-forum.author-pane.tpl

Nothing. Then I try going to the module folder and delete the "advanced-forum.naked.author-pane.tpl" file. Then, the template just dissapeared, and it was a big blank space where before were author_pane contents.
It still wouldn´t take my custom template in my theme folder.

I´ve cleared cache several times, there´s no difference.

Wat should I try to make it work?

Comment: The instructions appear to be for D6. Are you using D7?

Comment: Yes, I´m using D7. I thought that, so I´ve tried other template formats... without any luck.

Comment: Have you tried the double hyphen, like advanced_forum--author_pane.tpl.php?

Comment: Hmm... hehe, no I didn´t... how silly, I´ll do that now...

Comment: UPDATE: Yes, I´ve tried that and it didn´t worked out.

Comment: If there is a possible conflict between author_pane and the D7 template system, perhaps you should move this to the D.O. [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/author_pane).